# How to provoke a module to initialize itself in natural order from top to bottom?

Tags: module, f#

Module initialization rules in F# are unexpectedly strange and entangled. How to guarantee all module's bindings accomplishment before application starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the initialisation rules are very complex. (Modules are initialised by static initialisers, the rules of which are given in the spec [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597617).)

I'm not aware of any way to achieve strict top-down evaluation of every binding in your module before *any* part of the module is referenced externally. I doubt one exists.

For that reason, it's usually best if modules can be constructed to not need initialisation. If you really do need (order-sensitive) initialisation, you'll often be better off with a class type.